# jquery slide off page

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-animate, slide

I am trying to create a few animations on page load and on button click.

On page load, the div should slide in from the bottom of the page. When the user clicks the button, the div slides off the top of the page then goes to the URL after the slide off completes.

The on load function (slide in from bottom) doesnt trigger at all, and I dont know how to tell it to go to the URL **after** the animation completes. [Here is a jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/W6Ype/)

```
<head> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 

<div id="content-container"> 
<div id="content" style="position:relative; z-index:2000;" >
<a href="http://google.com" id="moveUp"><button>button</button></a>
</div> 
</div> 

<div id="panel"> 
<div class="content"> 
<img src="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png" width="122"><br /><br /> 
</div> 
</div> 

<script>
// On load panel slides in from bottom of page
$(function() {
  $("#panel").one('load', function () {
      $("#panel").animate({
            marginBottom: "-=1250px", height: "+=50px" }, 1000);
      }).each(function() {
    if(this.complete) $(this).load();
  });
});

// On click slide panel off the top of page
$("#moveUp").click(function(){
     $("#panel").animate({
          marginTop: "-=250px",          
          height: "+=50px"
    }, 1000);

  // After animation completes THEN go to URl???
   $(this)........;
});
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: You didn't tell us what the error actually is.  Please let us know what problem you are facing and we can try to help!

Comment: Thanks @slifty I edited the text. The on load doesnt work and I dont know how to tell the animation to complete before referring to the URL

Comment: Thanks for the edit - but I still need you to tell me what you mean by "won't work" -- for example do you mean doesn't get triggered at all?  it does but then nothing happens?  It causes an unexpected animation?  If you have FireBug or Chrome you can look at the console and DOM to see what's happening a little better.

Comment: @slifty the on load doesnt trigger, it seems like the script is treating it like an image rather than trying to load the whole div. Ive uploaded a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W6Ype/) if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning your on load issue:

Remember, the $(function()); syntax is shorthand for:

$(document).load(function() {})

In other words, by the time that code is run #panel will have already loaded.  This is why your event handler is never being called!  You aren't adding the listener until after the event has already been triggered

Try this instead:

```
$(function() {
  $("#panel").animate({
    marginBottom: "-=1250px", height: "+=50px" }, 1000);
  });
});
```

As for the URL after animate issue, you can add a callback to an animation by passing in a third parameter.  This parameter lets you define a function which gets called after the animation completes.

Try this:

```
$("#moveUp").click(function(){
     $("#panel").animate({
          marginTop: "-=250px",          
          height: "+=50px"
    }, 1000,
    function() {
        window.location="http://google.com";
    });
});
```

Comment: There we go! Sheesh, now I see what I was doing wrong. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to try and work out exactly what you are trying to accomplish but this
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ChiBlaaa/hSrtP/1/) might help

All i've done is absolutely positioned the div and then on load change the `top` value so that it animates in from the bottom.

Comment: Thats exactly it! Your resolution combined with @slifty's came out exactly as I was hoping. Thanks so much!